# Google Analytics: "The requested URL /analytics/v3/data/realtime/ was not found on this server"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

A few days ago the link below no longer responded.

I visited the official API page but there is no change information.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime/?ids=ga:191832042&dimensions=rt:deviceCategory,rt:pageTitle,rt:pagePath&metrics=rt:activeUsers&access_token=ya29.c.Kl2vB0gdtdSb1TBKB1DPCsP5T-Uc7KrTkvXC4rkfDXvx6evqgY0G6kVYRh4Fysdx3Z2P_fqa_eRq6GdXwDZV_Y0o_yiSbMCW1Ie19w7vMqKdyWfLVE7idhc5pcKszmY
```

The error below is shown when accessing the link above:

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /analytics/v3/data/realtime/ was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I thought it had something to do with a quota or something, but I couldn't really find any evidence of that, since everything works through OAuth and not some API key with limits.

So I just found out the reason was the trailing slash at the end.

So this:

```
/analytics/v3/data/realtime/...
```

Should be:

```
/analytics/v3/data/realtime...
```